# Are properties declared as private by default?

Tags: php, oop

I have the property `$value` which gives different error messages depending on whether I prepend `private` to the variable declaration or not.

```
Class Node{
        $value = NULL;
        public function __construct($value){
                $this->value = $value;
        }
}

$node = new Node('hello');
echo $node->value;
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/ubuntu/new.php on line 4

However if I replace `$value = NULL;` with  `private $value = NULL;` I get a different error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Node::$value in /home/ubuntu/new.php on line 11

I thought omitting the term private would automatically make the property private?

**EDIT**

I understand now that properties are public by default.  How come I get an error when declaring the property `$value` without the `public` prepended to it?

Comment: Undeclared properties are public by default (e.g. assigning values to them somewhere in your class-methods without prior declaration). Your example is just a syntax error ;)

Comment: You should [review the documentation on properties](http://php.net/language.oop5.properties).

Comment: You must write `class Node{ public $value=NULL etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got firs error **before**

```
echo $node->value;
```

Put class code without calling it and you'll get same error.

You just have syntax error on line:

```
 $value = NULL;
```

Replace with:

```
var $value = NULL;
```

### UPDATE

But this is wrong solution just to show where are your problem. **Always** set variable [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) one of:

- private
- protected
- public

Comment: `var $value`? So whats the standard for doing it with a more modern PHP version? Let's say 5.3?

Comment: @dbf OP trying to understand why code doesn't work without private, in case it need to be default for variable. This sample is showing how to declare variable without setting it private but getting it private. But of course you are right. need to set variables with one of `private/protected/public`.

Comment: Updated the answer to avoid misunderstood.

Comment: Why don't you just change your answer so it says `public $value = NULL;` instead of  `var $value = NULL;`?

Comment: @BoltClock Because in that case OP will get right answer but didn't understand where is his problem now.

Comment: How is it any different? `var` does not need to be used anymore - this isn't PHP 4 code.

Comment: I'm using `PHP 5.3.10` and with `var` it works. As I can see from question user knows about visibility options (at least about `private`). He heard that it's possible to declare variable without public. I show how, and update that always need to use **right visibility options**... Where is the problem? :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP default [Visiblity](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) is public. I guess You thought is private as it is default value in Java and other OO languages.

//edit

My little mistake, variables has mandatory visibility, part about public as default is about methods.
I recommend to always specify what level You need to avoid confusion.

var keyword is an alias for public (they kept if for compatibility reasons)